# How to disable default day-off in Team Foundation Server capacity calender?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops, scrum

I want to add capacity of my team members to sprint capacity, But Sat & Sun aren't days off in my country. Can I disable day-off for this calender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need TFS 2013 Update 2 or later:

- Hit the admin page for the project (usually
  http://server:8080/tfs/collection/project/_admin)
- Select the team that you need to configure
- Beside "Members" there is a "Settings" tab.
- Choose the working days for the team.

Configure and customize Agile planning tools for a team project
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543813.aspx